# Pymongo How to update specific value of row in array

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, pymongo

I have this simple JSON in mongodb:

```
{
        "pwd_list": [
            {
                "pwd": "password1",
                "pwd_date": str(int(time.time()))
            },
            {
                "pwd": "password2",
                "pwd_date": str(int(time.time()))
            },
       ]
}
```

What I am simply trying to do is to update one of the row of the `pwd_list` array using an index...

I tried to use the `$position` of mongodb but it seems to only work with `$push` but I don't want to push!

I'm using `pymongo`.

So I tried different things like this one:

```
self.collection.update({"email": "email"},
            {
            "$set": {
                "pwd_list": {
                            "temp_passwd": "NEW VALUE",
                            "temp_date": "str(int(time.time()))"
                            }   
                   }
            })
```

But it it not working as expected. (The above example is transforming the array in object...)

If it is not possible, can I at least update the first row (always this one)?

Comment: Did you check the documentation: https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/python/update/ ?

Comment: You say that you want to update one of the entries in pwd_list. How do you determine which one to update?

Comment: @lesingerouge Determining wich one I want is not really the problem. Just imagine I want the first one, how can I do that ? :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options when doing this.
If you want to search for a specific item to change, you should do the following:

```
self.collection.update({"email": "email", "pwd_list.pwd": "Password2"},
        {
        "$set": {
            "pwd_list.$": {
                        "pwd": "NEW VALUE",
                        "pwd_date": "str(int(time.time()))"
                        }   
               }
        })
```

If you want to change a specific item, and you know the position of the item in the array, you should do the following (in my example I am changing the first item):

```
self.collection.update({"email": "email"},
        {
        "$set": {
            "pwd_list.0": {
                        "pwd": "NEW VALUE",
                        "pwd_date": "str(int(time.time()))"
                        }   
               }
        })
```

You can find more details about this on [this page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/).

Comment: The second one is exactly what I was searching for ! thank a lot !